# Problem at timing in communicating nodes?

Tags: python, callback, nodes, publisher, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,
I'm really newbie to ROS and what I am trying to do is to make an architecture in which there is a ***Simulator*** that compute his trajectory in every moment and a **Controller** that get the Simulator's position (x,y,theta) at every t and pass the params (v,w) in order to compute the next position in which Simulator has to go. To do this, Simulator publish his position in */stateTopic*, Controller is subscribed to /stateTopic so it gets the values, does the maths, and publish new params v,w in */paramsTopic*. What I want, and what I'm failing to do, is that Simulator gets the new params, compute the next position and publish it to /stateTopic.  When I try to run this, it just doesn't work, nothing get publish on screen. Is a timing trouble?

------Simulator.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from std_msgs.msg import String
from comunicating_robots.msg import Position, Params
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import threading
#uso la classe InfoGetter per ottenere come risposta il messaggio da paramsTopic
class InfoGetter(object):
    def __init__(self):
       #event that will block until the info is received
       self._event = threading.Event()
       #attribute for storing the rx'd message
       self._msg = None
   def __call__(self, msg):
       #Uses __call__ so the object itself acts as the callback
       #save the data, trigger the event
       self._msg = msg
       self._event.set()
   def get_msg(self, timeout=None):
       """Blocks until the data is rx'd with optional timeout
       Returns the received message
       """
       self._event.wait(timeout)
       return self._msg
#funzione per calcolare nuova posizione
def newPosition(state, t, v, w):
    # unpack the state vector
    x = state[0]
    y = state[1]
    theta = state[2]
    #compute state derivatives
    xd = v*np.cos(theta)
    yd = v*np.sin(theta)
    thetad = w;
    #return the state derivatives
    return [xd, yd, thetad]

def publishState():
    global pub 
   #definisco stato iniziale e divido il tempo in passi da 0.01secondi
   state0 = [1.0, 1.0, 4.0]
   t = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.01)
   #risolvo il sistema di equazioni usando la funzione odeint di scipy.integrate  v=1 w=0 condizioni iniziali
   state = odeint(newPosition, state0, t, args=(1,0))
   rate = rospy.Rate(100) # 100hz
   #Get the info
   ig = InfoGetter()
   sub = rospy.Subscriber('paramsTopic', Params, ig)
   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      #creo e publico il messaggio
      msg = Position()
      msg.x = float(state[0][0])
      msg.y = float(state[0][1])
      msg.theta = float(state[0][2])
      rospy.loginfo(msg)
      pub.publish(msg)
     #prendo i nuovi parametri e risolvo l'equazione differenziale 
     #ig.get_msg() Blocks until message is received
      params = ig.get_msg()
      state = odeint(newPosition, state0, t, args=(floatparams.v),float(params.w)))   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
      #dichiaro il nodo al master e definisco il topic a cui mando messaggi di tipo Position (x,y,theta)
      rospy.init_node('simulator', anonymous=True)
      pub = rospy.Publisher('stateTopic', Position, queue_size=10)
      publishState()
   except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
```

------Controller.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from comunicating_robots.msg import Position, Params
def callback(data):
   global pub
   rospy.loginfo('I heard '+str(data.x)+' '+str(data.y)+' '+str(data.theta))
   #prendo x,y,z e li uso per calcolare i nuovi parametri
   publishParams(data.x, data.y, data.theta, pub)
def publishParams(x, y, theta, pub):
   try:
      rate = rospy.Rate(100) # 100hz
      msg = Params()    
      msg.v = x
      msg.w = y*theta
      rospy.loginfo(msg)
      pub.publish(msg)
   except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
      pass
def listener():
   sub = rospy.Subscriber('stateTopic', Position, callback)
   # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
   rospy.spin()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   rospy.init_node('controller', anonymous=True)
   pub = rospy.Publisher('paramsTopic', Params, queue_size=10)
   listener()
```

-----Position.msg:
float64 x
float64 y
float64 theta

-----Params.msg
float64 v
float64 w

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268310/problem-at-timing-in-communicating-nodes?/) by [thejesseslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31465/thejesseslayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it. The problem was that controller takes some time to subscribe to simulator topic and viceversa. So I put this in my code:

```
   con_rate=rospy.Rate(rate)
   while pub.get_num_connections() == 0:
   con_rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [thejesseslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31465/thejesseslayer/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1